# ImportError: cannot import name 'deprecated' when import gensim

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, gensim

everyone!
I'm trying to import gensim on jupyter but I got the following error:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'deprecated'`

What can I do?

PS: I tried in gensim version 3.8.1 and 3.8.3

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the full, exact error message shown, including all involved stack frames (code & line-numbers)?